# Why do some questions hardly get any views?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, quality-improvement, views

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440790/what-kind-of-pdf-signature-fields-are-standard-for-business-settings-in-the-us

I posted this question 4 days ago, along the way noticing the low number of views and editing it hoping to catch more views and attempts at answers. Nothing seems to have worked though.

Am I in the wrong community? I searched for "law" and "standards", only found law.stackexchange.com Would my question be more appropriate there?

Comment: First, is this actually a programming question? You haven't tagged it with any language or platform, and I don't know if anyone actively watches [pdf]. Are you sure that you're asking on the right site?

Comment: Only 1 in 4 questions in the [pdf] tag get an answer.  Multiply those odds by the attractiveness of your title and the views rapidly dwindle.  The days that SO users could reliably count on getting any answer at all are long gone, far too many questions and not enough helping hands left.

Comment: @BradLarson "Basically, my question is whether or not Foxit Phantom's siguature field is standard practice in the USA for signing legal documents, and if not, what is. This business deals with consumers, not other businesses." yeah, that's off topic.

Comment: @BradLarson, I think asking if I'm in the wrong community answers the last bit of your comment, I don't see why you asked that. As for whether or not it's programming, not really. For some reason, I thought it was at the time, without having really thought about it.

Comment: @HansPassant, dang O_O hadn't thought to look at the ratio there, thanks...I think 1 in 4 is overstating it, even

Comment: If this is about signature, more people will know the answer on security.stackexchange. They won't engage themselves about the legal aspect, but they will know if the USA gouvernement recommand this type of signature or another.

Comment: @BradLarson: I follow [tag:pdf], but only for questions regarding the actual file type itself. I re-tag lots and lots of questions which use PDF in a passing sense ("how do i show a list of pdf files in my app") and vote-to-close blatant write-me-code ("tell me how to add a sig using C#"). There are a couple of PDF library maintainers who do pretty much the same. (Hi Bruno, Amedee!) Questions about PDF "law" and "standards" seem OT or opiniated, though ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tags a question has and how many people follow those tags can have a big impact on how much visibility a question has. The tags on that question are all tags with very few followers, 920 across all tags. Also with the tags on those questions I wouldn't think that anyone would be actively following them so they would have no reason to see the question.

- pdf - 702
- standards - 82
- digital-signature - 123
- electronic-signature 13

Also I would say that this is not a programming question and is more of a business/legal question as you want to know the requirements rather then questions about implementing it.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to where WOULD be an appropriate place for it?

Comment: @donutguy640 Unfortunately I do not as I am not familiar enough with the various legal/business sites to know if it would be on topic for any of them.